# Prevent Spring Data for Mongo to convert ids to ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using Spring Data for Mongo on an existing database. The previous application used plain strings for ids instead of ObjectId.

My problem is that Spring Data insists on converting the strings to ObjectId, which makes all queries by id to fail.

For example, when I do `repository.findOne('')`, the query executed is `{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50cf9f34458cf91108ceb2b4"}}` when it should be `{ "_id" : "50cf9f34458cf91108ceb2b4" }`

Is there a way to avoid Spring Data to convert string ids to ObjectId?

Thanks!

Diego

Comment: Could you please provide more code input? SD MongoDB does *not* force all `String`s into `ObjectId`s. If you have `String` values for ids that can be converted into `ObjectId` as MongoDB is optimized to be used with these. Beyond that the query execution also does the same mapping when queries are executed so you shouldn't see the behavior you see in the first place. Would you mind adding the domain class, the repository declaration (your `findOne('')` doesn't make too much sense as well as client code trying to persist and read the object?

Comment: @OliverGierke I have the same issue here where some of my entity have Ids that are systematically assigned by converting ObjectId to string. Yes in this case we need to enforce Ids as string. Hence the  logic _If you have String values for ids that can be converted into ObjectId_ is failing for us.

Comment: @OliverGierke I also have this issue. Is there a solution meanwhile? Thanks

Comment: @OliverGierke Would it be possible to add another annotation like NoDefaultConversion to Id fields to prevent the default conversion from String to ObjectId? At the moment every number with a length of 24 is treated as a valid object id.

Comment: Issue created: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1798

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution for this. Probably not the best option, but works.

What I did was remove the converter from `String` to `ObjectId` that `MongoTemplate` uses through `QueryMapper`. This way, I created the following Mongo converter:

```
public class CustomMongoConverter extends MappingMongoConverter {
    public CustomMongoConverter(MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory, MappingContext<? extends MongoPersistentEntity<?>, MongoPersistentProperty> mappingContext) {
        super(mongoDbFactory, mappingContext);
        conversionService.addConverter(new Converter<String, ObjectId>() {
            @Override
            public ObjectId convert(String source) {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And then, I passed that implementation of the converter to `MongoTemplate`:

```
<bean id="mongoConverter" class="com.abcompany.model.repositories.utils.CustomMongoConverter">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate" id="mongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoConverter"/>
</bean>
```

This way, when trying to convert from String to ObjectId, it throws an exception and it doesn't do it. Please note that you probably can just remove the converter from `conversionService`.

Comment: Your solution works if you never going to use Mongo's ObjectId. Once you plan to use ObjectId the solution fails

Comment: What's the type of conversionService object?

Comment: can you please suggest by using completely annotation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Field annotation.

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.FieldType;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document    
public class Dog{
@Id
@Field(targetType = FieldType.STRING)
String myId;
...
}
```

Comment: It works perfect, it is the most flexible and practical way.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced same problem and my solution was like below:

```
  @Bean
  public MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter(MongoDbFactory factory, MongoMappingContext context, CustomConversions conversions) {
    MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(new DefaultDbRefResolver(factory), context) {
      @Override
      public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        conversions.registerConvertersIn(conversionService);
      }
    };
    converter.setCustomConversions(conversions);
    return converter;
  }
```

The idea is to prevent default converters registration.

Comment: It did prevent default converter registration (in `AbstractMongoConverter`), but Spring did use other converter and mapped it to ObjectId that I'm not aware of, so it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

now enough just override convertId method in MappingMongoConverter.

default here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/master/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/convert/MongoConverter.java#L128. As we can see, conversionService will no so helpful.

that's part of my config (I don't need ObjectId from string at all in my collections):

```
@Configuration
public class MongoCommonConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {
    ...
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(MongoDbFactory dbFactory, 
        MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter) {
        return new MongoTemplate(dbFactory, mappingMongoConverter);
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @Override
    public @NotNull MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter() throws Exception {
        DbRefResolver dbRefResolver = new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDbFactory());
        MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(dbRefResolver, mongoMappingContext()) {
            @Override
            public Object convertId(Object id, @NotNull Class<?> targetType) {
                return id;
            }
        };
        converter.setCustomConversions(customConversions());
        converter.setCodecRegistryProvider(mongoDbFactory());

        return converter;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a simpler approach to the same one [serhii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3215626/serhii)
took where you only override the method `convertId` in `MobileMappingMongoConverter` class, you'll find it in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65069850/5726051).

Answer (score 0):

Field annotation with FieldType=IMPLICIT worked for me

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.FieldType;

public class FilesInUploading {

    @Id
    @Field(targetType = FieldType.IMPLICIT)
    private String id;
...

}
```

I also tried with `FieldType=STRING`. But `$nin, $in` queries not worked for me at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow if you are not able to use annotations on the entity class then you can extend CachingMongoPersistentProperty to override isIdProperty() method.
This will prevent converting "id" properties to "_id":

```
public class NotEditableEntityMongoPersistentProperty extends CachingMongoPersistentProperty {

  public NotEditableEntityMongoPersistentProperty(final Property property, final MongoPersistentEntity<?> owner,
      final SimpleTypeHolder simpleTypeHolder, final FieldNamingStrategy fieldNamingStrategy) {
    super(property, owner, simpleTypeHolder, fieldNamingStrategy);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isIdProperty() {
    return false;
  }

}
```

Then use this on MongoMappingContext:

```
public class NotEditableEntityMongoMappingContext extends MongoMappingContext {
    
  @Override
  public MongoPersistentProperty createPersistentProperty(final Property property, final BasicMongoPersistentEntity<?> owner,
      final SimpleTypeHolder simpleTypeHolder) {
    return new NotEditableEntityMongoPersistentProperty(property, owner, simpleTypeHolder, PropertyNameFieldNamingStrategy.INSTANCE);
  }
}
```

Then

```
  @Bean
  public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(@Autowired final MongoDatabaseFactory mongoDbFactory) {
    DbRefResolver dbRefResolver = new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDbFactory);

    MongoMappingContext mappingContext = new NotEditableEntityMongoMappingContext();
    MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(dbRefResolver, mappingContext);

    return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory, converter);
  }
```