# How to use Mongo with Spring Data without ObjectId

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have an existing mongo database in which ids (_id) are persisted as plain Strings.. This is sample data in Mongo DB:

```
{
    "_id" : "528bb0e2e4b0442f1479f1b4",
    "schoolId" : "URDLKYLFJXLWJGR193778316742298",
    "surname" : "Lewis",
    "admissionNumber" : "0347",
    "firstName" : "Martins"
}
```

I have a Java object which is of the form:

```
public class Student {

@Id
private String id;
private String schoolId;
private String surname;
private String admissionNumber;
private String firstName;
}
```

With Getters and Setters

I also have a repository:

```
public interface StudentRepository extends MongoRepository<Student, String> {

    Student findOneBySurname(String surname);
    Student findOneById(String id);
    Student findOneBySurnameAndFirstName(String surname, String firstName);
}
```

When I do a studentRepository.findAll() I am able to get all the Students in the database with all their fields populated correctly.

When I do a studentRepository.findOne("528bb0e2e4b0442f1479f1b4") or a studentRepository.findOneById)"528bb0e2e4b0442f1479f1b4") it returns null

When I do a debug of the mongo query I can see that it is calling:

```
2015-11-19 16:06:32.327 DEBUG 87081 --- [           main] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : findOne using query: { "id" : "528bb0e2e4b0442f1479f1b4"} fields: null for class: class com.ad.josh.domain.Student in collection: Student
    2015-11-19 16:06:32.331 DEBUG 87081 --- [           main] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils       : Getting Mongo Database name=[joshdb]
    2015-11-19 16:06:32.333 DEBUG 87081 --- [           main] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : findOne using query: { "_id" : { "$oid" : "528bb0e2e4b0442f1479f1b4"}} in db.collection: josh.Student
```

Typically I can see that it is still querying with Object Id and not a plain String.

I have seen suggestions to:

[Create a Converter which throws a RuntimeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329175/prevent-spring-data-for-mongo-to-convert-ids-to-objectid)

But this does not work; it just throws a RuntimeException.

Any suggestions on how to use Spring Data to access a Mongo database where the Ids are defined as String already (in an existing database) would be really appreciated.

Comment: This one pretty much looks like a bug in Spring Data MongoDB as the `QueryMapper` turns any `String` that is a valid `ObjectId` into an `ObjectId` (see: [QueryMapper#convertId](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/1.8.1.RELEASE/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/convert/QueryMapper.java#L476)). I've created [DATAMONGO-1333](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1333) to investigate on that.

Comment: Thanks @ChristophStrobl that's helpful to know

Comment: That works as [expected and documented](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.conventions.id-field). Strings that are valid ObjectIds are persisted as such in the database. Care to provide a test case that shows the repository query not returning an instance of a just persisted instance?

Comment: So @OliverGierke if an object (Java) has an id which is a string and is persisted, it saves to the db with ObjectId, and if you go ahead to return an instance by supplying the id in String it returns fine. However the problem is there is an existing database with ids which are not stored as ObjectId in MongoDB. If one goes ahead to query using the id (As String), it returns null because it is expecting the MongoDB to have records stored with ObjectIds (While it is stored in plain String)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is a wrong "_id" format and that is why Mongo cannot recognize any object with such id. It should looks like  **ObjectId**("528bb0e2e4b0442f1479f1b4"), not plain String type.

```
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("528bb0e2e4b0442f1479f1b4"),
            "schoolId" : "URDLKYLFJXLWJGR193778316742298",
            "surname" : "Lewis",
            "admissionNumber" : "0347",
            "firstName" : "Martins"
        }
```

So if you have imported .json with existing data to mongo you need to change id:

```
"_id": {$oid:"528bb0e2e4b0442f1479f1b4"},
```

And it should be converted to correct format.

Hope it can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different `MongoTemplate` per repository as described here: [Configure Multiple MongoDB repositories with Spring Data Mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681546/configure-multiple-mongodb-repositories-with-spring-data-mongo) 
In the repository that you don't want the conversion from String to ObjectId you have to use mongoTemplate that will lack `ObjectIdToStringConverter`

Comment: I'd suggest that too.

Answer (score 0):

There's a converter behind which does this conversion out of the box for you, if you'd like to keep String id's as they're and not convert them to ObjectId you have to override the convertId method in the `MappingMongoConverter` class, I've made an example here:

```
/*
* Note that this example I've tried on spring-data-mongodb.3.0.4.RELEASE version 
* and it's not guaranteed that it will work with earlier versions 
* yet the approach should be similar
*/
@Component
public class CustomMappingMongoConverter extends MappingMongoConverter {

    public CustomMappingMongoConverter(MappingContext<? extends MongoPersistentEntity<?>, MongoPersistentProperty> mappingContext) {    
        //The constructor can differ based on the version and the dbRefResolver instance as well
        super(NoOpDbRefResolver.INSTANCE, mappingContext);
    }

    @Override
    public Object convertId(Object id, Class<?> targetType) {
        if (id == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (ClassUtils.isAssignable(ObjectId.class, targetType) && id instanceof String && ObjectId.isValid(id.toString())) {
            return id;
        }
        return super.convertId(id, targetType);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

A workaround that could work is to create your own converter for ObjectId.

You can customize the mongo mapper by supplying a @Bean of type MappingMongoConverter

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {

    @Bean
    public CustomConversions customConversions() {
        List<Converter<?, ?>> converters = new ArrayList<Converter<?, ?>>();
        converters.add(new MyObjectIdConverter());
        return new CustomConversions(converters);
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter(MongoDbFactory factory, MongoMappingContext context, BeanFactory beanFactory) {
        DbRefResolver dbRefResolver = new DefaultDbRefResolver(factory);
        MappingMongoConverter mappingConverter = new MappingMongoConverter(dbRefResolver, context);
        try {
            mappingConverter.setCustomConversions(customConversions());
        }
        catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException ignore) {}

        // Don't save _class to mongo
        mappingConverter.setTypeMapper(new DefaultMongoTypeMapper(null));

        return mappingConverter;
    }

}
```

Comment: The code will not do what it claims. This code will not allow a String to be used for _id insetad of ObjectId, so it is not a correct answer.