# Java mongoTemplate findOne query not returning results when id is String

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

I have the below query to find MongoDB document using mongoTemplate.
This is not returning any results when I search my Target using Id.

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("id").is(String.valueOf(targetId)));
mongoTemplate.findOne(query, Target.class));
```

But the query works when I use any fields other than Id. Could someone help me to work this using Id.

Target class

```
@Data
@Document
public class Target {
    @Id
    private String id;
    /**
     * Name of the target
     */
    private String name;
}
```

DB document.

```
{
    "_id" : "5290d748e4",
    "name" : "Test Target"
}
```

Query By name is working fine.

```
Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("name").is("Test Target"));
mongoTemplate.findOne(query, Target.class));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the required functionality by using `MongoCollection`.

```
MongoDatabase mongoDatabase = mongoTemplate.getDb();
MongoCollection<Document> targetCollection
                    = mongoDatabase.getCollection(mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(Target.class));
Document query = new Document();
query.put("_id", parkTargetId);
query.put("spots._id", parkingSpotId);

targetCollection.find(query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33809010/how-to-use-mongo-with-spring-data-without-objectid), it looks like this is not possible to achieve. You need to change the type in database as `ObjectId`.

If you cannot do that, you can do

```
mongoTemplate.getCollection("target").findOne(<targetId>)
```

But this will return a `DBObject`, You need to create Target instance from this

Comment: This also doesnt work. The id field in mongodb is String.  ```{'_id': "1234"}```

Comment: can you put your Target class also

Comment: But ```mongoTemplate.findById(targetId)``` works fine. I need this to work with ```findOne``` and ```updateFirst```. Which are not working at the moment.

Comment: added Target class to the question.

Comment: did u try this `new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(new ObjectId(targetId)));`

Comment: can u show a sample document which is there in database

Comment: added sample db document